# Modify a big Sqlite DB via SFTP

Tags: python, database, sqlite, networking, ssh

A distant server has a 1 GB Sqlite database file `/home/test/data.db`.

I need to download it locally, modify a few rows (maybe 100 KB) and update the distant server accordingly, but **without** resending *the whole* `data.db` 1GB file!

Something like this:

```
import pysftp, sqlite3

with pysftp.Connection('192.168.0.10', username='root', password='testpwd') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('/home/test/'):           
        sftp.get('data.db')  # wait a few seconds or minutes to download 1 GB...

        conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1289, 'hello')")
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 41")
        conn.commit()

        # how to update the distant server's /home/test/data.db
        # without resending 1GB of data?
```

or

```
import pysftp, sqlite3, io

with pysftp.Connection('192.168.0.10', username='root', password='testpwd') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('/home/test/'):           
        file_obj = io.BytesIO()
        sftp.getfo('data.db', file_obj)  

        # how to open file_obj with sqlite3 ?
        conn = sqlite3.connect(file_obj)

        conn.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1289, 'hello')")
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 41")
        conn.commit()

        # how to update the distant server without resending 1GB of data over network?
```

Note:

- I don't want to use a database server (such as MySQL, etc.) on the distant computer, because I only have SFTP access there; I can't install a new database server there
- Also I can't execute arbitrary SSH commands on the remote server (such as `sqlite3 ...` or run a Python script on the remote server that adds/removes rows with `sqlite3`), only SFTP commands are allowed

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1134061/is-there-an-ftp-or-ftp-like-client-which-allows-delta-uploads-i-e-only-uplo